# Combine 3 graphs into 1 and add additional labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

I would like to make the following figure:
[image]

So, far I have made only each curve in separate figures. How can I combine them into one? How can I have the dashed lines and how can I add the '1st stage', '2nd stage' etc and how the 'strictly increasing' label?

My code so far separately is:
For TP curve

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin = 0,
  xmax = 8,
  ymin = 0,
  ymax = 18, 
  axis lines = left,
  xlabel = $L$,
  ylabel = $Q$
  ]
  \addplot+[mark = none] coordinates {%
    (0,0) 
    (1,3)
    (2,8)
    (3,12)
    (4,15)
    (5,17)
    (6,17)
    (7,16)};
\coordinate (A) at (axis cs:0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (axis cs:1,3);
\coordinate (C) at (axis cs:2,8);
\coordinate (D) at (axis cs:3,12);
\coordinate (E) at (axis cs:4,15);
\coordinate (F) at (axis cs:5,17);
\coordinate (G) at (axis cs:6,17);
\coordinate (H) at (axis cs:7,16);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

For AP:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begn{axis}[
  xmin = 0,
  xmax = 8,
  ymin = 0,
  ymax = 18, 
  axis lines = left,
  xlabel = $L$,
  ylabel = $Q$
  ]
  \addplot+[mark = none] coordinates {%
    (0,0) 
    (1,3)
    (2,4)
    (3,4)
    (4,3.75)
    (5,3.4)
    (6,2.8)
    (7,2.2)};
\coordinate (A) at (axis cs:0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (axis cs:1,3);
\coordinate (C) at (axis cs:2,4);
\coordinate (D) at (axis cs:3,4);
\coordinate (E) at (axis cs:4,3.75);
\coordinate (F) at (axis cs:5,3.4);
\coordinate (G) at (axis cs:6,2.8);
\coordinate (H) at (axis cs:7,2.2);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

For MP:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin = 0,
  xmax = 8,
  ymin = 0,
  ymax = 18, 
  axis lines = left,
  xlabel = $L$,
  ylabel = $Q$
  ]
  \addplot+[mark = none] coordinates {%
    (0,0) 
    (1,3)
    (2,5)
    (3,4)
    (4,3)
    (5,2)
    (6,0)
    (7,-1)};
\coordinate (A) at (axis cs:0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (axis cs:1,3);
\coordinate (C) at (axis cs:2,5);
\coordinate (D) at (axis cs:3,4);
\coordinate (E) at (axis cs:4,3);
\coordinate (F) at (axis cs:5,2);
\coordinate (G) at (axis cs:6,0);
\coordinate (H) at (axis cs:7,-1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Finally, do you know if there is an add-in for Excel that converts its charts into Latex code (as the there is one for tables)?

Comment: This site works best if you ask just one question per post. At the moment there's four. To answer the last one: No, there's no such add-in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To combine all plots into one picture, just add them all into one axis environment.

You can add the dashed lines and the labels using:

```
\draw[dashed] (axis cs:2,0) -- (axis cs:2,20); % dashed line
\node at (axis cs:1,18) {1st stage};           % label
```

Here is a full example:

```
\documentclass[border=.5cm]{standalone}

\title{pgfplots - motor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  xmin = 0,
  xmax = 8,
  ymin = -5,
  ymax = 20,      
  xlabel = $L$,
  ylabel = $Q$,
  xlabel near ticks,
  ylabel near ticks,
  extra y ticks       = {-5,5,10,15,20},
  extra y tick labels = ,
  extra y tick style  = {grid = major},
  legend style={at={(axis cs:8.5,10)},anchor=west}
  ]
  \addplot+[mark = none, smooth] coordinates {%
    (0,0) 
    (1,3)
    (2,8)
    (3,12)
    (4,15)
    (5,17)
    (6,17)
    (7,16)};
  \addlegendentry{TP}
  \addplot+[mark = none, smooth] coordinates {%
    (0,0) 
    (1,3)
    (2,4)
    (3,4)
    (4,3.75)
    (5,3.4)
    (6,2.8)
    (7,2.2)};
  \addlegendentry{AP}
  \addplot+[mark = none, smooth] coordinates {%
    (0,0) 
    (1,3)
    (2,5)
    (3,4)
    (4,3)
    (5,2)
    (6,0)
    (7,-1)};
  \addlegendentry{MP}

    \draw[dashed] (axis cs:2,0) -- (axis cs:2,20);
    \draw[dashed] (axis cs:6,0) -- (axis cs:6,20);

    \node at (axis cs:1,18) {1st stage};
    \node at (axis cs:4,18) {2nd stage};
    \node at (axis cs:7,18) {3rd stage};

    \node[rotate=45] at (axis cs:.7,3.8)
        {\tiny \parbox{1.2cm}{strictly\\ increasing}};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplots]

Comment: That's very hepful. How can I draw the the point (7,-1) below the x-line?

Comment: @giannis remove the `ymin = 0` setting or change it to `-1`, or so.

Comment: @sergejIt was the first thing that I've tried, but the result doesn't look like the image I've uploaded above.

Comment: @giannis See my updated answer

Comment: @giannis You could also try out the `grid = major` setting.

Comment: Could we have the x-axis and y-axis at (0,0) and the point (-1,0) get below the x-axis, so as to have the same result as the image uploaded above?

Comment: @giannis Change `axis lines=left` to `axis lines=middle`.